# Cycling through changing image source is defaulting to previous one it changed to if the next option has been done before

Tags: javascript

I'm currently (attempting to) make a rock paper scissors game have hand animations for the odin project and upon making the computer's hand go up and down a few times I have it show either a rock, paper or scissors image. It works fine the first time the computer selects either rock, paper or scissors (e.g. if comp picks rock then paper they both work) but then if it goes back to picking rock again it will show paper until it picks scissors & then it will keep showing scissors.

I've tried changing functions, moving things around, changing variables and parameters/arguments all to no avail. If anyone could take a look and tell me where the problem lies or what to look into to figure out how to fix I'd really appreciate it.

I'm just going to put the whole section of javascript code as I've no clue where the issue.

```
let playerRock = document.getElementById('rock');
let playerPaper = document.getElementById('paper');
let playerScissors = document.getElementById('scissors');
let playerScore = 0;
let computerScore = 0;
let computerChoice;
let animation = document.querySelector('#animated');
const playerScoreDisplay = document.querySelector('#playerScore');
const compScoreDisplay = document.querySelector('#computerScore');
const resultsDisplay = document.querySelector('#result');
const resultsContainer = document.querySelector('#resultsContainer');

playerRock.addEventListener('click', playRock);
playerPaper.addEventListener('click', playPaper);
playerScissors.addEventListener('click', playScissors);

function generateNumber() {
  return Math.floor(Math.random() * 3);
}

function computerSelection(n) {
  if (n === 0) {
    n = 'rock';
  } else if (n === 1) {
    n = 'paper';
  } else if (n === 2) {
    n = 'scissors';
  }
  return n;
}

function animateComputer() {
  animation.src = 'img/rock.png';
  animation.classList.toggle('animate');
  setTimeout(function() {
    animation.classList.toggle('animate');
  }, 1600);
}

function animateEnd() {
  if (computerChoice === 'rock') {
    animation.addEventListener('animationend', updateRock);
  } else if (computerChoice === 'paper') {
    animation.addEventListener('animationend', updatePaper);
  } else if (computerChoice === 'scissors') {
    animation.addEventListener('animationend', updateScissors);
  }
}

function updatePaper() {
  animation.src = 'img/paper.png';
}
function updateRock() {
  animation.src = 'img/rock.png';
}
function updateScissors() {
  animation.src = 'img/scissors.png';
}

function playRock() {
  computerChoice = computerSelection(generateNumber());
  if (computerChoice === 'scissors') {
    return playerScore++,
    setTimeout(function() {
      resultsContainer.style.backgroundColor = '#9aa5bd';
      playerScoreDisplay.textContent = `Player Score: ${playerScore}` ,
      compScoreDisplay.textContent = `Player Score: ${computerScore}`,
      resultsDisplay.textContent = `WIN!`  }, 1600),
    animateComputer(),
    animateEnd();
  } else if (computerChoice === 'rock') {
    setTimeout(function() {
      resultsContainer.style.backgroundColor = '#9aa5bd';
      playerScoreDisplay.textContent = `Player Score: ${playerScore}`,
      compScoreDisplay.textContent = `Player Score: ${computerScore}`,
      resultsDisplay.textContent = `DRAW!`
    }, 1600),
    animateComputer(),
    animateEnd();
  } else  if (computerChoice === 'paper') {
    computerScore++,
    setTimeout(function() {
      resultsContainer.style.backgroundColor = '#9aa5bd';
      playerScoreDisplay.textContent = `Player Score: ${playerScore}`,
      compScoreDisplay.textContent = `Player Score: ${computerScore}`,
      resultsDisplay.textContent = `LOSE!`
    }, 1600),
    animateComputer(),
    animateEnd();
  } else {
    console.log(`I have no idea what you've done here...`);
  }
}

function playPaper() {
  computerChoice = computerSelection(generateNumber());
  if (computerChoice === 'rock') {
    return playerScore++,
      setTimeout(function() {
        resultsContainer.style.backgroundColor = '#9aa5bd';
        playerScoreDisplay.textContent = `Player Score: ${playerScore}` ,
        compScoreDisplay.textContent = `Player Score: ${computerScore}`,
        resultsDisplay.textContent = `WIN!`
      }, 1600),
      animateComputer(),
      animateEnd();
  } else if (computerChoice === 'paper') {
      setTimeout(function() {
        resultsContainer.style.backgroundColor = '#9aa5bd';
        playerScoreDisplay.textContent = `Player Score: ${playerScore}`,
        compScoreDisplay.textContent = `Player Score: ${computerScore}`,
        resultsDisplay.textContent = `DRAW!`
      }, 1600),
      animateComputer(),
      animateEnd();
  } else  if (computerChoice === 'scissors') {
    computerScore++,
    setTimeout(function() {
      resultsContainer.style.backgroundColor = '#9aa5bd';
      playerScoreDisplay.textContent = `Player Score: ${playerScore}`,
      compScoreDisplay.textContent = `Player Score: ${computerScore}`,
      resultsDisplay.textContent = `LOSE!`
    }, 1600),
    animateComputer(),
    animateEnd();
  } else {
    console.log(`I have no idea what you've done here...`);
  }
}

function playScissors() {
  computerChoice = computerSelection(generateNumber());
  if (computerChoice === 'paper') {
    return playerScore++,
    setTimeout(function() {
      resultsContainer.style.backgroundColor = '#9aa5bd';
      playerScoreDisplay.textContent = `Player Score: ${playerScore}` ,
      compScoreDisplay.textContent = `Player Score: ${computerScore}`,
      resultsDisplay.textContent = `WIN!`
    }, 1600),
    animateComputer(),
    animateEnd();
  } else if (computerChoice === 'scissors') {
      setTimeout(function() {
        resultsContainer.style.backgroundColor = '#9aa5bd';
        playerScoreDisplay.textContent = `Player Score: ${playerScore}`,
        compScoreDisplay.textContent = `Player Score: ${computerScore}`,
        resultsDisplay.textContent = `DRAW!`
      }, 1600),
      animateComputer(),
      animateEnd();
  } else  if (computerChoice === 'rock') {
    computerScore++,
    setTimeout(function() {
      resultsContainer.style.backgroundColor = '#9aa5bd';
      playerScoreDisplay.textContent = `Player Score: ${playerScore}`,
      compScoreDisplay.textContent = `Player Score: ${computerScore}`,
      resultsDisplay.textContent = `LOSE!`
    }, 1600),
    animateComputer(),
    animateEnd();
  } else {
    console.log(`I have no idea what you've done here...`);
  }
}
```

TIA to anyone that helps.

Adding a link to my github where this is posted in case people need that to help, differences in the code quoted here & code in my github is just merged the animateComputer and animateEnd functions & changed if's to switches.

https://github.com/Chealkiin/rock-paper-scissors

Comment: In case anyone runs into a similar issue; the fix was to add this code underneath each event listener inside the animateEnd function: `setTimeout(function() {
        animation.removeEventListener('animationend', updateScissors);
      }, 1600); `